# Thick "Initial" font, with a particular "S"

Tags: fonts, font-weight

I want wondering if anyone knew of any *commercial-free* fonts where the "S" doesn't curve down, but instead the ends go horizontally? I'm having a hard time searching for something with that kind of wording. I'm looking for an impact like font (in terms of thickness).

So below is an image, of an "S" where it curves down, but as mentioned I'd want it to come out horizontally.
[image]

Comment: Had a short browser on www.dafont.com, the retro and sci-fi categories have lots of S's with horizontal ends, but none i saw resemble 'impact' closely. If you can't find something there, another option may be to take it into illustrator and convert to outlines, then manipulate the font face. This could be ok if you just need to modify one character

Comment: Yeah. It doesn't necessarily need to be like Impact, just heavy like Impact. I actually found a pretty neat font called Newtown that is a nice and heavy font and has a the "S" I'm looking for. Best of all, it's free for commercial use.

Comment: Cool, add your comment as an answer when you can (and maybe a link or image of the fontface)

Comment: @Jaips - did so :]

Comment: There aren't going to be many (if any) extra-bold, extra-condensed faces like Impact that have the truncated S. You're likely better off customizing an S yourself to fit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I found a nice, bold font](http://www.fontspace.com/roger-white/newtown) with the `S` I was looking for.

[image]

[image]

The `S` isn't perfect, so I'll use illustrator to make it to my liking.

Comment: Looks to be a very poor clone/trace of Handel Gothic.

Comment: not sure I'd call that a 'nice' face. But if the S works...

Comment: Some google sleuthing seems to prove e100 correct: http://www.typophile.com/node/30593

Comment: Oh, I realize it's not a very nice fact. But, I only need three captial letters and with a little adjustment it's just what I need. Also thank you for pointing that out about the font. Stuff like that really irritates me.