# Which free fonts are similar to this sans-serif Handel Gothic font?

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation, sans-serif, free

What is the font in this extract?

[image: font to identify]

(hint: I've already found that it looks very similar to Handel Gothic, but the M is round on top)

and what free (or even open-source if possible) font (to use in a printed book) could I use to replace it?

**Edit:**

I actually decided to replace it with Roger White's Newtown:
http://www.fontspace.com/roger-white/newtown:

[image: using newtown]

**Edit:**

I fixed the small caps by ``thinnering'' the font as explained [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4192). The small caps have been adapted to the height and width of the small "x". The capital "S" is still bigger because that's part of the way it's supposed to look. Here is the result:

[image: newtown with small caps fixed]

It's not strictly the same, but close enough for my needs, and the font is free (GPL actually) :-)

Comment: The newer one is (slightly) better but please fix the fake small caps so that they are all the same weight.

Comment: On one of my old questions we came across a topic where Newtown seems to be a poor copy of Handel Gothic. (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/thick-initial-font-with-a-particular-s)

Comment: @DA01: how would I "fix" the small caps?

Comment: True small caps are designed to match the weight of the standard caps, but only as tall as the x-height. If you need to fake them, then you need to spend time getting the weight of the S to match the weight of the MITH characters. Thin out the S a bit and beef up the MITH a bit. Or, alternatively consider using a typeface with a full set of small caps already built.

Comment: @DA01: How would I make the small caps thinner in Inkscape for example?

Comment: Ah, I found this http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4192 which works fine :-)

Comment: As Johannes alludes above, the problem is that Newtown is of dubious provenance and quality - just look at the foot of the "S".

Comment: @e100: I know, I can tell. That said, my budget doesn't allow me to buy a font just for this, so it'll have to do :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It started out as Handel Gothic Medium (the Linotype version), by the look of it, but the letterforms have been s-t-r-e-t-c-h-e-d horizontally (I hate that) and the M has been rounded for purposes of creating this wordmark. The stretching is what makes the vertical parts of the S, T and C, and the vertical strokes of the T, H and K too thick, so they're out of proportion.

Note that these are faux small caps, not the real thing (which are rare in sans serif typefaces). That's why the initial caps are thicker than the lower case.

Answer (score 4):

Handel Gothic seems about right. I couldn't find a free font that looked even remotely similar to this (I even passed it through a font identification system, but it found a font that looked nothing like it), but if you can pay the $24.99 or so for Handel Gothic on MyFont, then you should go for it.

Also, if you do end up getting Handel Gothic, I found that doing some erasing from the points of the M work fine. A very rough example:

[image: edited Handel Gothic]
<sub>(source: [imm.io](http://i.imm.io/70d9.png))</sub>

Photoshop has the crescent-shaped eraser that would work great for this if you manipulate it well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Modaerne Regular, stretched horizontally a little. It is indeed similar to Handel.

Unfortunately I'm looking for a third font similar to both...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112524)